# Change font on google bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, fonts, google-visualization

I'm trying to change the font for everything on a google bar chart.  It works for everything but the tooltip.  At least, I think it's called the tooltip--it's the font that shown when you mouse over a bar.  I think I'm doing it correctly according to the docs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family: bebas;
                src: url(BebasNeue.otf);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="font-family:bebas;">This font changed</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['bar']}]}"></script>
               <div id="cheese_plot" style="width: 900px; height: 500px; font-family:bebas;"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

            var rawdata = [["Swiss", 90],
                ["Cheddah", 75],
                ["'Merican", 35],
                ["Le bleu", 65],
                ['Stinky', 70]];
            var labels = [['Cheese', 'Pieces']];

            var fullArray = labels.concat(rawdata);

            function drawStuff() {
                var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
                    fullArray
                );



                var options = {
                    annotations: {textStyle: { fontName: 'bebas' }},
                    hAxis: {textStyle: { fontName: 'bebas' }, titleTextStyle: { fontName: 'bebas' }},
                    vAxis: {textStyle: { fontName: 'bebas' }, titleTextStyle: { fontName: 'bebas' }},
                    titleTextStyle: { fontName: 'bebas' },
                    tooltip: {textStyle: {fontName: 'bebas' }},
                    fontName: 'bebas',
                    fontSize: 24,
                    title: 'Cheeseses',
                    width: 900,
                    legend: { position: 'none' },
                    chart: { title: 'Cheese',
                    subtitle: 'pieces' },
                    bars: 'horizontal',
                    axes: {
                    x:  {0: { side: 'top', label: 'Pieces'}}},
                    bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
                };

                var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('cheese_plot'));
                chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
              };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are the docs: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart?hl=it#data-format

I am trying to use a custom font I got from here: http://www.dafont.com/bebas-neue.font

Is this a google charts bug, am I doing something wrong; is this even possible?

Comment: Not that it's terribly helpful, but you misspelled `Cheeseses`.

Comment: That was intentional.

Comment: Just to confirm, the font is being used for all elements in the chart *except* the tooltip?

Comment: The font is successfully changed on everything but the tooltip.  I want it to be changed for everything INCLUDING the tooltip.

Comment: I have determined that you *can* set the tooltip font, but haven't worked it into your example.

Comment: You cannot change the tooltip font last I checked but there are articles online about how to replace the tooltip with something else.

Comment: @Rob After much testing I have determined that using HTML tooltips (or changing the font) is not yet supported by Material Charts. Same code works fine for corecharts.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/vEbuOsWHzK8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material Charts are still in beta so `convertOptions` probably just isn't working for the tooltip. Use CSS instead.

```
#cheese_plot text{
    font-family:'bebas' !important;
}
```

**Edit:** The tooltips are nested within two `<g>` elements, whereas none of the other `text` blocks are, so you can isolate the tooltip CSS like so if you'd like:

```
#cheese_plot g g text{
    font-family:'bebas' !important;
    fill:red !important;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfo2L1d/)

Comment: Nice work, how were you able to figure that out with the nested g's? Looking at the 'elements' tab in the developer tools window in chrome, I can see a 'g' element being added when I mouse over a bar, but I'm unable to keep the element there as I move over to expand it (the 'g' element disappears after I mouse off).

Comment: Tooltips are always a pain to find because of that, but you can usually see where they're being created by toggling them on and off. I just keep my mouse hovering and use my keyboard to navigate to and expand the elements.

Comment: I see.  I just noticed another problem: the box around the tooltip text doesn't change size, so it doesn't fit different types of texts properly.

Comment: You might have to manually tweak the padding settings or the font-size, but if you look at the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfo2L1d/3/), it's definitely resizing.